# Prepopulate Text Input From Select Using Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout and am prepopulating a select list with values. I would like these values to be copied to a textbox, but for the user to be able to override whatever is in the textbox. Currently, when the textbox loses focus, its value is reverting to the currently selected value of the dropdownlist.

ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.services = ['/api/trainers', '/api/trainingcategories']
self.selectedApi = ko.observable('/api/trainers');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>API</label>
<select data-bind="options: services,
        optionsCaption: 'Choose an API...',
        value: selectedApi,
        valueAllowUnset: true"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: selectedApi" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Call API</button>
</div>
```

I thought that setting valueAllowUnset would have the effect of blanking out the select element whenever the selectedApi value was set to something that wasn't in the list of options, but that isn't the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting when the textbox loses focus?

Comment: The select list should become blank (that's what the docs say should happen when valueAllowUnset is true), and the viewModel value of selectedApi should have the value specified in the textbox.

Comment: and this is exactly what your code is doing. Type something in textbox and press tab button to blur. https://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/u2e0gquv/1/

Comment: Interesting. Obviously, it's not working on my page, but I see the expected behavior on your fiddle; let me try to isolate the problem.

Comment: It's working for me. Your problem is likely in code you've not shared. https://jsfiddle.net/fvfdobyo/

Comment: The issue was my version of knockout was out of date - updated to latest and problem solved. Thanks for the assist! Feel free to add an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

The `valueAllowUnset` option was added in version 3.1.0 of Knockout. You must use that or a later version for the option to have an effect.